Difference between radio transmitter roll-off and bandwidth-time (BT) product
For any radio transmitter, the output signal will likely have a shape filter to manage bandwidth. However I am struggling to understand the relationship between a roll-off (e.g. 0.35) and a bandwidth-time product (e.g. 3dB bandwidth * symbol rate). I have always assumed them to be interchangeable, where either a roll-off or BT value can be used to calculate the extra bandwidth occupied by the datastream:

Bandwidth = SymbolRate*(1+BT) = SymbolRate*(1+RollOff)

I've found a radio with a roll-off of 0.20, yet the datasheet states an occupied bandwidth of:

1.07 * SymbolRate for 99% occupied bandwidth
1.18 * SymbolRate for 99.9% occupied bandwidth

Why would there be a smaller bandwidth that the nominal roll-off value of 0.2? And what is the difference between this 99% and 99.9% value?
